# What does the IRS do about trivial tax discrepancies?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

I submitted my taxes (e-file) about a week ago via Turbotax - expecting a large refund. I then unexpectedly received a 1099-INT from my bank for $15 of interest received during the year. I did not include this with my return. Obviously I'd pay the tax on that trivial amount, but my bigger concern is what the IRS is going to do with this discrepancy. Ideally they'd just correct it internally, adjust my refund, and send me a notice - but I do not know their operating procedures. I later learned that 1099-INTs aren't sent out for amounts under $10, which is likely why I haven't run into this issue before.

Since they receive this form too, will they automatically realize the error and reject my return? Will they not care since the underreported amount is so minor (since they don't care about <10)? Will it simply delay my return?

Comment: I once received a refund from my state for just over $1, due to an unexplained correction to my return. So it's certainly possible that the IRS *could* notice and adjust your refund accordingly. Whether they *will*, or whether it is a good idea to correct the oversight yourself, is not something I can answer.

Comment: Regarding interest amounts under $10 - you are still supposed to include them into your income, and pay tax on them, even though the bank does not send you the form 1099-INT. From what you are saying, it sounds like you've not been doing that in the past years. So, in this sense, this year is no different.

Comment: I've had this happen to me twice, once in my favor and once not.  In both cases, they processed my return and then notified my of the discrepancy.  In the case where I was deficient, the notification included the explanation of adjustments as well as the amount underpaid plus a minor amount of interest.  In the opposite scenario, they also processed the return but instead, refunded my overpayment.  Worst case scenario is that  you will learn how to make license plates at the Spiro Agnew Minimum Security Facility :->)

Comment: Just in case you missed the joke in Baerker's answer, you will NOT get in trouble.

Comment: @Bob Baerker: Probably not, since license plates are a state thing.  Don't know what they have you do in federal prisons.

Comment: I could wonder why you submitted early, since they won't process until next week, but ... if your taxable income (line 11) is under $100k your tax is (mandatorily) determined using tables with $50 brackets, so there's a 70% chance adding $15 in income doesn't change your tax at all. Most 1099's are due to _you_ by Jan 31 but not due to IRS until March, so it's unlikely they will catch this item before issuing your refund. If they do catch it later, they _may_ send you a notice proposing an adjustment, or they may decide it's below threshold and drop it.

Comment: @jamesqf - There's always someone in the audience who can't accept humor for what it is.

Comment: @Bob Baerker: Pot, meet Kettle :-)

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar issue two years ago. It was about $80, and I had reported the income combined with other similar things as a miscellaneous income entry but the IRS would have no way of knowing the income from that 1099 was included in that section. I still haven't heard from them.